# UDF runs twice in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a simple spark dataframe that has two columns, both strings; One called `id` and the other called `name`. I also have a Python function called `string_replacement` that does some string manipulation. I've defined a wrapper UDF that encompasses `string_replacement` and applies to every row of the data frame. Only the `name` column is passed to the string manipulation function. Here is the code

```
# Import libraries
from pyspark.sql import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Create Example Dataframe

row1 = Row(id='123456', name='Computer Science')

df = spark.createDataFrame([row1])

# Print the dataframe
df.show()

# Define function that does some string operations
def string_replacement(input_string):
    string=input_string
    string=string.replace('Computer', 'Computer x')
    string=string.replace('Science', 'Science x')
    return string


# Define wrapper function to turn into UFD

def wrapper_func(row):
    temp=row[1]
    temp=string_replacement(temp)
    row[1]=temp

    return row


# Create the schema for the resulting data frame
output_schema = StructType([StructField('id', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('name', StringType(), True)])


# UDF to apply the wrapper function to the dataframe
new_udf=f.udf(lambda z: wrapper_func(z), output_schema)

cols=df.columns
new_df=df.select(new_udf(f.array(cols)).alias('results')).select(f.col('results.*'))

new_df.show(truncate = False)
```

The function takes the word `Computer` and turns it into `Computer x`. It does the same for the word `Science`.

The original dataframe looks like this

```
+------+----------------+
|    id|            name|
+------+----------------+
|123456|Computer Science|
+------+----------------+
```

After applying the function, it looks like this

```
+------+------------------------+
|id    |name                    |
+------+------------------------+
|123456|Computer x x Science x x|
+------+------------------------+
```

As you can tell by the `x x`s, it has run the function twice. The second time on the output of the first run. **How can I avoid this behavior?**

Interestingly, if I don't explode the resultant dataframe, it looks fine:

```
new_df=df.select(new_udf(f.array(cols)).alias('results'))
```

gives you

```
+-----------------------------+
|results                      |
+-----------------------------+
|[123456,Computer x Science x]|
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Also if you're just doing simple replacements, you're way better of using [`pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace).

Comment: Sorry, copy-pasted from the wrong file. I've corrected it.

Comment: For more context, I ran into this issue with a more complicated function so created this toy script that replicates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using star expansion seems to result in running UDF once for each expanded element, as can be seen here.

```
df.select(new_udf(F.array(cols)).alias('results')).select(F.col('results.*')).explain()

# == Physical Plan ==
# *(1) Project [pythonUDF1#109.id AS id#104, pythonUDF1#109.name AS name#105]
# +- BatchEvalPython [<lambda>(array(id#0, name#1)), <lambda>(array(id#0, name#1))], [id#0, name#1, pythonUDF0#108, pythonUDF1#109]
#    +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#0,name#1]
```

If you want to keep your current code structure, you can solve the problem by wrapping it in an array and doing an explode.

```
df.select(F.explode(F.array(new_udf(F.array(cols)))).alias('results')).select(F.col('results.*')).show(truncate=False)

# +------+--------------------+
# |id    |name                |
# +------+--------------------+
# |123456|Computer x Science x|
# +------+--------------------+
```

Depending on your use case, the code is more readable if you can re-implement the UDF in this way, i.e. processing only a specific column per row rather than the whole row.

```
def rep_str(string):
    res = string
    res = res.replace('Computer', 'Computer x')
    res = res.replace('Science', 'Science x')
    return res

rep_str_udf = F.udf(lambda s: rep_str(s), StringType())

df.withColumn('new_name', rep_str_udf(df.name)).show()

# +------+----------------+--------------------+
# |    id|            name|            new_name|
# +------+----------------+--------------------+
# |123456|Computer Science|Computer x Science x|
# +------+----------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Cylim! I had the same problem as OP. Do you have an idea _why_ wrapping with explode(array(...)) works? It seems a bit magic...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks cylim. This also seems to work but your approach is clearer.

```
def string_replacement(string1, string2):
    string2=string2.replace('Computer', 'Computer x')
    string2=string2.replace('Science', 'Science x')
    return string1, string2

output_schema = StructType([StructField('id', StringType(), True), StructField('name', StringType(), True)])

new_udf=f.udf(string_replacement, output_schema)

cols=df.columns
df.select( new_udf(f.col('id'), f.col('name')).alias('results')).select(f.col('results.*')).show(truncate = False)
```